# Auto activate virtual environment in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, virtualenv, visual-studio-code

I want VS Code to turn venv on run, but I can't find how to do that.
I already tried to add to settings.json this line:

> "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["source${workspaceFolder}\env\Scripts\activate"]

But, it throws me an 127 error code. I found what 127 code means. It means, `Not found`. But how it can be not found, if I see my venv folder in my eyes right now?

I think it's terminal fault. I'm using Win 10 with Git Bash terminal, that comes when you install Git to your machine.

Comment: I don't think you need this line at all.  Try removing this entire line from your settings and VS Code should handle the workspace venv for you.

Comment: @Krrr yep, it did, but it did on .py file start, not IDE at all as I want

Comment: @Krrr nope, terminal shows line as env is not actived.

Comment: @Krrr yea, in my workspace i have `env`, `.vscode`  and my project folders.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is how I did it in 2021:

1. Enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in your vs code.
2. Locate your Virtual Environment:

   **Python: select interpreter** > **Enter interpreter path** > **Find**
3. Once you locate your virtual env select your python version:

   **your-virtual-env** > **bin** > **python3**.
4. Now in your project you will see **.vscode** directory created open **settings.json** inside of it and add:

   `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true`

   don't forget to add comma before to separate it with already present key value pair.
5. Now restart the terminal.

You should see your virtual environment activated automatically.

Comment: this solution requires creating a new terminal to activate the `venv`, the solution of @moojen is more elegant, activating the `venv` in the current terminal.

Comment: This worked for me.  However, I did not have to edit  the settings.json file.  Once I did the "find", I selected my virtual environment python.exe file from a Windows file dialog.  I am using virtualenv instead of env.  My path is: ".\.venvs\<project folder name>\Scripts\python.exe".  Once I closed and re-opened the terminal, it was showing prefix of my <project folder name>.  Only my virtual project has nose2 installed and it was recognized in the editor now.

Comment: "python.terminal.activateEnvironment" is true by default. It will require closing and reopening the default terminal in order to activate the venv.

Comment: There was no 'settings.json' file in my .vscode directory. Just argv.json and launch.json

Comment: According to current vscode docs, pipenv, venv and pyenv (the three most common virtual envs) all respond to this setting in .vscode/settings.json which @BrianReinhold isn't always created automatically, it is a 'per workspace' file I believe, that VSCode will (sometimes) prompt you to create.

Comment: If you don't have `settings.json` or even `.vscode`, instead of creating it manually you can do `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` and enter `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)`

Comment: As has been mentioned, modifying `settings.json` is not needed for this answer, just steps 1-3 (`activateEnvironment` is set to `true` by default). And it only works for new terminals. To make it work for default terminal on startup, use `activateEnvInCurrentTerminal`.

Comment: At first this didn't work for me, but I then did `Python: Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting` and did the steps and it worked without having to change anything in `settings.json` file

Answer (score 53):

Actually the earlier suggested solutions didn't work for me, instead I added the following in my settings:

```
"settings": {
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "~/venv/bin/python"
}
```

Of course replace the defaultInterpreterPath (used to be pythonPath) setting with your own path (so don't copy/paste the second line).

Comment: This works for the built-in terminal. However I have some defined build steps for my Python project. I like to you use VSCode tasks for these. Do you know how to also activate the Python venv for tasks in VSCode?

Comment: If you virtual environment is defined in at the root of the project's directory for the current project you should use: `${workspaceFolder}` as the prefix.

Comment: Be careful with setting the `defaultInterpreterPath` in your `settings.json` as it will become the default for all of your VSCode projects. It is better to select it as described in steps 1-3 of @Ahtisham's answer above so it is stored specifically for that folder/workspace ([source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters)).

Answer (score 21):

You don't need this line at all.  Just remove it and switch your Python interpreter to point to the one within your `venv`.  [Here's a relevant documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) (italicized emphasis mine):

> To select a specific environment, use the **Python: Select Interpreter**
>   command from the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).
>
> ... and
>   opening a terminal with the **Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal**
>   command. In the latter case, *VS Code automatically activated the
>   selected environment.*

Once you switch the interpreter VS code should create a `.vscode` folder within your workspace with a `settings.json` indicating the python interpreter.  This will give VS code the direction of where to locate the `venv`.

Comment: It will still not activate the venv in the terminal unless you create a new Terminal instance.

Comment: These instructions are so incomplete. What is "this line"? "create a `.vscode` folder within your workspace with a `settings.json` indicating the python interpreter".. you don't explain how to indicate the python interpreter either.

Answer (score 12):

There is a new flag that one can use: `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true`

Answer (score 5):

VS Code should do this by default if it can find your interpreter.

If for some reason it cannot or it is located in some other folder, the best way to do this is to follow these 2 simple steps:

1. **Set the interpreter for your current folder/workspace**

   a. Enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> from VS Code

   b. Select "Python: Select Interpreter"

   c. Locate the appropriate virtual environment by either:

   - Picking it from the options in the list
   - Or clicking "Enter interpreter path...", then "Find...", and finding the right interpreter/Python executable
2. **Set needed configurations in your `settings.json`**

   - Make sure the environment gets automatically activated on window open:

     ```
     "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true
     ```
   - (Optional) Internally, `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment"` is set to `true` by default. To not automatically activate this environment by default for a new terminal, set it to `false` in your `settings.json`.
3. (Optional) You can also set the `defaultInterpreterPath` as the Python interpreter that will be used by default for your VS Code folders and workspaces. But you likely want to **avoid doing this** if you have multiple environments locally for your different folders/workspaces.

   ```
   "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/path/to/bin/python"
   ```

Source: [VS Code Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters)

**Note**: this does not seem to work for all terminal windows if you have multiple "History restored" ones when opening a new VS Code window.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create /.vscode/settings.json manually

Here is the tree;

```
├───django
│   ├───.vscode
│   │   ├───settings.json
```

I created /.vscode/settings.json then added this code in settings.json  (I am using windows so I used double backslash for path location otherwise it gives unicode error, and don't copy paste this, find your own .virtualenvs)

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Talha\\.virtualenvs\\django-okd21pq9\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my scenario was pretty much the same. I am running VSCode on Windows, wanting to used git bash as my default Terminal but after the venv got created, it was doing some weird stuff when a Terminal would open where it couldn't find the correct python interpeter in the venv/Scripts folder even though I did ctrl-shift-p a bunch of times to reset it to the python.exe there. I also wanted to make sure the  activate script was run on Terminal open. I just couldn't get the debugger to work right and it kept complaining that it could not find the python interpreter, so I basically couldn't debug at all.

So for anyone who is having weird stuff happen trying to use a Git Bash Terminal in VSCode in Windows related to a python project using a virtual env, here is what I found out;

1. I noticed that when I opened a new Git Bash Terminal, and looked at the $PATH variable to make sure it could find the interpreter in the venv, the path to the venv/Scripts folder would be prepended to the $PATH, but not with linux path separators like everything else in $PATH but with a Windows style path;

```
echo $PATH
C:\Users\blah\Documents\blah\Stock-down\Dev\this_api\venv/Scripts:/c/Users/blah/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/blah/bin:/c/Program Files/Go/bin:/c/Python39/Scripts:
```

So whenever I would try to debug, or just even run which python, It would get confused and thought the interpreter was in here;

```
which python
C:\Users\blah\Documents\blah\Stock-down\Dev\this_api\venv/Scripts/C/Users/blah/Documents/blah/Stock-down/Dev/this_api/venv/Scripts/python.exe
```

2. I ran the "printenv" command in the Terminal to see what env vars were getting set and why the venv interpreter path was getting messed up. And I found a env var I didn't know existed - VIRTUAL_ENV. But I didn't know how it was getting set or where it came from. After some pain, and hunting around I found it - when you run "python -m venv venvname" to create the virtual env in the project folder, as you know, it creates the activate (and activate.bat for windows) scripts in the ./venv/Scripts folder. Inside these files this VIRTUAL_ENV variable is not only exported, but but prepended to the $PATH variable on Terminal open with the "/Scripts" folder name added in linux path style. The problem with is that it sets the VIRTUAL_ENV value with windows type path - I know its painful and wrong to do this, but I just changed it to what Git Bash is expecting, see below;

```
#unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

#VIRTUAL_ENV="C:\Users\blah\Documents\blah\Stock-down\Dev\this_api\venv"
VIRTUAL_ENV="/c/Users/blah/Documents/blah/Stock-down/Dev/st_api/venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/Scripts:$PATH"
export PATH
```

3. Now when a new Git Bash Terminal is opened it prepends the venv/Scripts path correctly to $PATH;

```
echo $PATH
/c/Users/blah/Documents/blah/Stock-down/Dev/st_api/venv/Scripts:/c/Users/blah/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/blah/bin:/c/Program Files/Go/bin:/c/Python39/Scripts:
```

3. I also made a copy of the executable python.exe in the ./venv/Scripts dir and just called it "python" and now the command "which python" works and I can debug fine. I still set ctrl-shift-P when I choose the interpreter in VSCODE to "python.exe" when I just use "find" during the selection.

For more information on VIRTUAL_ENV var, see this doc -- [python venv docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

It feels like jumping through a bunch of hoops I know, but this way I can open a new Git Bash Terminal, have the activate script run correctly on Terminal Open, debug, and operate normally without having to float between Git Bash AND WSL Ubuntu AND Powershell, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My environment started to activate automatically after the advice from this [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

> When you create a new virtual environment, a prompt will be displayed
> to allow you to select it for the workspace. This will add the path to
> the Python interpreter from the new virtual environment to your
> workspace settings. That environment will then be used when installing
> packages and running code through the Python extension. For examples
> of using virtual environment in projects, see the Python, Django, and
> Flash tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, search for `User Settings (JSON)`
2. Add the following two lines:

   ##### Solution for Windows

   ```json
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
   ```

   ##### Solution for Linux

   ```json
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python"",
   ```

#### Note

The above assumes that:

- you place your environment in your workspace folder, i.e. *at the root of your repository*
- your default environment is called `.venv`. You can change this in the settings to whatever you prefer, as per instructions.

For Linux users, I'd personally avoid solutions placing the environment in the home folder (i.e. `~/venv/bin/python`) – you really should have 1 environment per project (i.e. repo).

I personally prefer the naming convention `.venv`, with a dot prefix rather than without. It has a few advantages: `.gitignore`s usually include folders with a dot prefix; it is usually hidden by default by Linux; it appears at the top of the folder list when visible.