# Why can't I activate my virtual environment in Visual Studio Code by just running files after creating the virtual environment in CMD

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

so I am using Python 3.12.2. I am using Visual Studio Code. I cloned a project I had made on my laptop onto my desktop. I created a virtual environment like I usually do with the command ("Python -m venv venv")(I usually have better names but project is simple so name wasn't too important). I can activate the virtual environment using the command venv\Scripts\activate.bat but I don't want to do this. I like the option of just running the python programs and have the venv automatically "activated" without having to always run this command. I am assuming this has something to do with my environment variables but I am unsure. I attached a screenshot of my environment variables if that helps.
I am using just the default venv module that comes with base python
[image]

Forgot to add that the interpreter is just 3.12.2('venv':venv). Probably isn't necessary to state but just trying to give as much useful info as possible.

EDIT: I fixed my problem, I needed to set python.terminal.activateEnvironment to True

Comment: you can select python interpreter from created virtual environment inside visual code .Then no need activate virtual environment inside IDE https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: I do have the venv interpreter selected

Comment: That is why i don't understand why nothing is working, my path variables also look completely fine as well

Comment: what happens if you open a terminal when you have the interpreter selected?, are you using CodeRunner?

Comment: what if you name your virt env `.venv`

Comment: First off: what is your understanding, of what happens when you activate a virtual environment? If you aren't clear on that, you should start there (this question is probably a duplicate, but I can't easily find a good reference here). If you do understand that activating the virtual environment *does something*, then I can't understand the question. It seems like you ask "why can't I get the effect of the virtual environment being activated, without explicitly activating it?"

Comment: If your idea is that running the Python code should cause the virtual environment to become active - **how**? First off, the point of the virtual environment is to choose which Python interpreter to use for the code. If the code is already running, then the interpreter has already been chosen. Second, how should Python know what virtual environments exist on the computer, or which one to use?

Comment: I think I confused you with how i phrased my question apologies. what I meant to say is I want my virtual environment always active. I can close the terminal whenever I want and close visual studio but whenever I reopen that project i won't have to constantly reactivate venv in the command line. I think this is a setting is visual studio if I remember correctly though but I may be wrong. It's been a while since I've had to do that

Comment: @KarlKnechtel in my VSC setup if I have selected a Pyton virt env and I open a terminal or I use F5 to run a Python file the first command on the terminal typed is the activation of the virt env. This command is "typed" by VSC. The next command is the actual `python.exe ...... debug stuff .......` command

Comment: Right, so, after that happens, what difficulty are you actually encountering?

Comment: I fixed the issue, I needed to set python.terminal.activateEnvironment in visual studio to True instead of false

Comment: It appears from the visual studio documenation this is default behavior which is why some people were confused by the question I asked

Comment: If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue and am posting it here in case people experience the same issue as me. If you find that your virtual environment in visual studio code is not being activated every time you open a new terminal you need to go to file -> preferences -> settings and from there search up python.terminal.activateEnvironment in the search bar and ensure you have this feature activated(checked). This is set to true by default though. There is another post with the same problem which was solved several years ago, I however did not find it when searching for a solution to my problem initially. Here is that post

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433333/auto-activate-virtual-environment-in-visual-studio-code#:~:text=Set%20needed%20configurations%20in%20your%20settings.json&text=(Optional)%20Internally%2C%20%22python,to%20false%20in%20your%20settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433333/auto-activate-virtual-environment-in-visual-studio-code#:%7E:text=Set%20needed%20configurations%20in%20your%20settings.json&text=(Optional)%20Internally%2C%20%22python,to%20false%20in%20your%20settings).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by chosing your python interpreter

Just use F1 -> Python: Select Interpreter -> Select your virtual environment
Then if you open a terminal or execute python file you should be using your virtual environment